# how much does plasma proplusion cost as compare to conventional fuel in spacecraft?

Tags: spacex, orbital-mechanics

I want to know how much does plasma propulsion cost as compare to other fuels in space crafts in the orbit

Comment: What kind of plasma are you thinking of? And are you including the cost of transporting the fuel to orbit?

Comment: plasma as fuel, plasma propulsion is a type of electric propulsion that generates thrust from a quasi-neutral plasma. I want to know want is the cost just the cost of the plasma in the satellite like Tacsat 2 which was working on the plasma.how much does the cost of the plasma in a normal satellite which uses plasma as a fuel

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you constrain further. You can't just pull out a conventional thruster and put in a plasma thruster with the same thrust and weight, there are too many differences. One big one is that the thrust is much lower for the plasma thrusters that have been demonstrated in space already. Another point is that the fuel is often a very small cost (except  for Xe?) I'd recommend you read a little bit about them first. You can start by looking at other questions here already that have the [`ion-thruster`](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ion-thruster)tag

Answer (score 1):

The thruster on Tac-SAT 2 was a [Hall effect thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-effect_thruster), one of a number of propulsion systems that use electric or magnetic fields, rather than heat, to accelerate their reaction mass, any of which could be called a plasma thruster. In all of them, the plasma is made in situ from some other suitable material, often (and in the case of Tac-SAT 2 (confirmed [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234985523_Plasma_properties_downstream_of_a_low-power_Hall_thruster))) Xenon gas.

On Earth [Xenon costs a few dollars per gram](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-much-does-xenon-gas-cost.636285/), which is expensive compared to typical chemical propellants for the same kind of job, such as [hydrazine, at a few dollars per kilogram](https://www.iridium.com/blog/2017/06/20/hydrazine-toxic-for-humans-but-satellites-love-it/) (although hydrazine is expensive to handle, and both fuels are probably more expensive at the required purity.

This is dwarfed though by the cost of lifting the fuel up into orbit, with is around $1000/kilogram even using the relatively cheap Falcon rockets.  The key thing, therefore is that you need less (by mass) Xenon to do the same work than you do hydrazine, because a Hall effect thruster ejects the reaction mass at a higher velocity than a chemical rocket can.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you lead me to how much fuel(xenon) takes in one cycle for Tac-SAT-2 types of rockets in space

Comment: What do you mean by a cycle?